# Convert function signature type and keep generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Actually, I was not sure of what to search, so maybe the question is already answered somewhere, but after 2 days of test and research I couldn't get it...

I'm creating a proxy which gonna call a backend, and has the backend's type. The thing is that sync methods gonna turn async, so I try to get type safety in the client by changing function signatures (kinda "promisify") from sync to async. For regular functions, everything works well, but when i comes to generics, I loose generic types in signatures, which turns to unknown...

I'm not sure there's a way to do this (yet) even with last TS version (currently 4.7.3), but maybe a TS type wizard have the solution?

The goal is to get

```js
const syncIdentity = <T>(o: T) => o;
// type is <T>(o:T) => T
const asyncIdentity = async <T>(o: T) => o;
// type is <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>

type PromisifiedSyncIdentity = Promisify<typeof syncIdentity>;
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
type PromisifiedAsyncIdentity = Promisify<typeof asyncIdentity>;
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
```

My first try was this:

```js
type Promisify<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: Parameters<F>) => Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<F>>>;

type PromisifiedSyncIdentity = Promisify<typeof syncIdentity>;
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
// got (o:unknown) => Promise<unknown> :-/
type PromisifiedAsyncIdentity = Promisify<typeof asyncIdentity>;
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
// got (o:unknown) => Promise<unknown> :-/
```

The second try keep generics when function already async (actually, keeps the original type)

```js
type Promisify<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = F extends (...args: any[]) => infer R
    ? R extends Promise<any>
        ? F
        : (...args: Parameters<F>) => Promise<ReturnType<F>>
    : never;

type PromisifiedSyncIdentity = Promisify<typeof syncIdentity>;
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
// got (o:unknown) => Promise<unknown> :-/
type PromisifiedAsyncIdentity = Promisify<typeof asyncIdentity>;
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
// got <T>(o:T) => Promise<T> (YEAH! :-D)
```

And that's it! I couldn't find any way to keep the generics when changing the function signature...
Would any talented TS coder have a solution for this? Or can tell me for sure it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're close on the mapped type approach, you just need to conditionally wrap the return value in a promise:

```typescript
type Promisify<FuncType extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    // This condition will always be true, it's purely to introduce
    // the mapping and infer the types
    FuncType extends (...args: infer ArgTypes) => infer RetType
    ? RetType extends Promise<any>
        // It already returns a promise
        ? FuncType
        // It doesn't return a promise, wrap the return type in a promise
        : (...args: ArgTypes) => Promise<RetType>
    // This will never happen, because of our type constraint
    : never;
```

Then you define your types with type parameters:

```
type PromisifiedSyncIdentity<T> = Promisify<typeof syncIdentity<T>>;
//   ^?
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
type PromisifiedAsyncIdentity<T> = Promisify<typeof asyncIdentity<T>>;
//   ^?
// want <T>(o:T) => Promise<T>
```

Then for instance, you can test it like this:

```
const f: PromisifiedSyncIdentity<string> = async (o: string) => o; // Works!
```

If there are more type params, you just handle that when doing the new type; `Promisify` itself is unchanged:

```typescript
type SyncWithTwoTypeParams<A, B> = (o: A) => B;

type PromisifiedSyncWithTwoTypeParams<A, B> = Promisify<SyncWithTwoTypeParams<A, B>>;

const f2: PromisifiedSyncWithTwoTypeParams<string, number> = async (o: string) => {
    return Number(o);
}; // Works!
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeZgEkAmBTMUCWV4wF4YAeAFQD4AKEALhlIEpDyYQBuAKAHouY8AHdDGwQSFajUbN6HUJFgBDBEjSYceQjCWJgYqrXpMCLdt14ChIvRKnGYABQBOIALYj0Zchw4WHztxDYAGbwxABiAK5IpPCCMOgAHlCYqKKUAHSZCo4A5hB0CmDwANoAukYshfAsBBww9TA89AAWVnKouNjgMADu2AA2-Vr9PQrwogBGQlCOEegANMJQAOSi-BGO6P34UCDCWM6oEcDodQ1NUM1CLgr8-NhgOVpgqPtB6I58V3yx6BBn9Ui0V+8SSKTSmXS2TydAe70+AEFcjFBBAKm8PjAAEroKAo04NGAAfmxuPxoOSL1ETlc7mIVS8hMJTWQin6mwUqHwmygG0gWhg-H87gBTJJQOA+NFzN4rJgqBAfzAy1gPL5AqFtIgC16jluXyEascYB+cQeGuF2ulDToGSyuXyMCROXxaOkNICHhxeN+jPOvFIrVEfUGMDA6AAbpjmrdBGBFlNgAoItrWEFWBtTUI5NA9Q8oKK6OGo45OD4QR6RMFsOhUABlHSqLC4UIUTSVwIhYgWEDp5QoDDNvCecicJr1AB6RLMvUKsE8NnRHY8FHLcQ71drCP7TfUrZqfi1wVCPfT2hUg73I7HvEn06aoyw1lothYy883hzsCCdA3QRr9aNpeLbELmDw5Ae566BIcAzOB6LsI0vAAOogI4ADWEAAITeL4DZIMhuDNKQPQgPi9jZAoLgQMQCKLAAQgeMEIui9Flr4f4AfhwCEZcJFkb8FF6tRtEMQef6hNxvHEaR5GUSJdEwIxo6fuA0AwEEABMv6WpugEEUR-FycJNFgY8ixgBELhTI4kH9jAMFmTk6IAN6ikaJoAHJWTZ1AMJwAC+bBITAqEYdhQA)